# Is it correct that for a real function f on a metric space, the set of points at which f is conti. is the $\cap$ of countable collection of open sets?

Tags: real-analysis

Seems like this is related to Baire's category thm. Can anyone explain why this is right?

Comment: @aduh I'm pretty sure it's the former because there are no countable open subsets of the real line in the usual topology.

Comment: Putting the entire problem statement in the title may seem to be economical or expeditious, but it usually requires skimping on the rigor or clarity of formulation.  The body of the Question is where a generously self-contained problem statement should appear.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For $\epsilon>0$, say that $f$ is **$\epsilon$-continuous at $x$** if there is some open ball $B\ni x$ such that for $a, b\in B$, we have $\vert f(a)-f(b)\vert<\epsilon$.

Can you show that for each $\epsilon$, the set $C(\epsilon)$ of points at which $f$ is $\epsilon$-continuous is an open set?

Can you show that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $x\in C(\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$?

Now just think about $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C({1\over n})$ . . .

Comment: I wrote up your hint as an answer. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

let S(n)=$\{x | |f(x)-f(y)|<1/n\ and\ \rho(x,y)<\delta_n \}$

For any $s\in S(n)$, there exists x and r such that B(s, r) $\subseteq$ B(x, $\delta_n$). Thus B(s, r) $\subseteq$ S(n) and S(n) is open.

Thus f is continuous at $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}s(n)$.